# Actionbarsherlock - change actionbar line colour

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-theme, android-styles

I am currently working on making my application compatible with pre 3.0 devices with the aid of actionbarsherlock. My application has a custom theme which overide Holo.light changing the blue to orange.

I am wanting to change the blue line which appears under the actionbar to orange. With the official actionbar I managed this by overriding

```
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ad_tab_unselected_holo</item>
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to be working in actionbarsherlock 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do two things:

The ABS 4 now mimics the standard Action bar with its attributes so you need to **add** -

```
<item name="background">@drawable/ad_tab_unselected_holo</item>
```

Notice the absence of `android:`

So your overall code would be:

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/ad_tab_unselected_holo</item>
<item name="background">@drawable/ad_tab_unselected_holo</item>
```

To quote:

> Due to limitations in Android's theming system any theme
>   customizations must be declared in two attributes. The normal
>   android-prefixed attributes apply the theme to the native action bar
>   and the unprefixed attributes are for the custom implementation. Since
>   both theming APIs are exactly the same you need only reference your
>   customizations twice rather than having to implement them twice.

I would also extend a varient of `Theme.Sherlock` rather than holo, as I believe holo is not available on older devices that are pre 3.0.

Comment: Yes, you need to extend Theme.Sherlock or another theme provided by ABS 4.

Comment: Also, in my findings, I need to have android:background AND background for styling to work consistently across all versions of Android. Maybe I'm flat out wrong or this changed, though.

Comment: Notice I said *add* - not replace therefore BOTH variants would be present.

Comment: I was caught up by the "Notice the absence of android:" This was before you had the `android:background` line above the `background` there.

Comment: After what you said I thought I would save some confusion and my point clear :)

Comment: Thanks don't know how I missed that. I have styled other aspects this way but simply overlooked this! 
I thought the point of Theme.holo was to bring holo back to devices prior to 3.0? It is successfully working on a device running 2.3 :)