# Change line color in tabs - ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

I'm using ActionBarSherlock to make my app compatible with older devices. The implementation was easy, but now i need to style the default Holo blue line that you see under the tabs to a red line.

I've been reading a few topics ([topic 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064411/change-actionbarsherlock-background-color), [topic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044303/actionbarsherlock-change-actionbar-line-colour)) here on SO and also the ABS doc ([link](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html)), but i can't get it to work.

This is what i have so far.

In my AndroidManifest.xml i added this line to the `application` tag.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" > <!-- SET THE DEFAULT THEME -->
```

Then in `res/values/styles.xml` i have:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />

    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#ff000000</item>
        <item name="background">#ff000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But when i run my app, then i still see the default blue line color.

What am i doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**

**Read this if you want to fully style your ActionBarSherlock!**

I found an answer here on SO which gave the following link:
http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator

It's an easy generator which generates all the needed files for a fully customized ABS! All you have to do is copy the generated files into the appropiate folders and you're set!

Don't forget to enable the style (you'll have to enter a **style name** in the generator) in your AndroidManifest. For that, see the answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few things:

You don't really need `<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />` anymore unless you want to change it to inherit `Theme.Sherlock` and use it for your app theme. If you decide to do this you will have to use `Theme.MyTheme` for activities.

Either way, to fix the problem you want to change

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
```

to

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme" >
```

OR you can apply the theme directly to your activities:

```
 <activity 
    android:name="com.awesome.package.activity.SomeActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"/>
```

Side note, I recommend this [excellent actionbar theme generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)

Comment: how to user it it's not dowloding?

Answer (score 1):

Set in your manifest file theme as follows:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme" >
```

It will preserve all Sherlock themes and will add your custom styles.